# Can't import projects into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

So, I'm able to import my project fine onto my desktop computer, but when I try on my laptop, there is a problem.  Basically, when I open the import wizard (by just clicking file, import) a window comes up that says "import, select, choose import source, select an import source:" but then, below "select an import source" there is just nothing to choose from.  There are some buttons that says back, next, and finish, but those are all grayed out.  The ONLY thing I can do is cancel.  There's supposed to be a text box that says "type filter text" and some things to choose from like the "general" folder so I can choose to import an archive file, but just none of that is there, there is nothing to do but cancel.  What gives?  This is rather frustrating.

Comment: What version of Eclipse you are using?

Comment: I'm using Kepler Service Release 2...

Comment: This is apparently still a problem in 2017. I can't import a project either- it simply disables the next button.